# What is causing memory leaks in my generic linked list in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, malloc

I have made my own generic linked list, however in my removeStart and removeLast functions, I keep getting memory leaks according to valgrind. Could anybody let me know why this is happening, and potentially some solutions?

Head file: LinkedList.h

```
  4 typedef struct LinkedListNode
  5 {
  6     void* data;
  7     struct LinkedListNode* next;
  8     struct LinkedListNode* previous;
  9 } LinkedListNode;
 10 
 11 typedef struct
 12 {
 13     LinkedListNode* head;
 14     LinkedListNode* tail;
 15     int size;
 16 } LinkedList;
```

Code: linkedlist.c

```
  5 /*******************************************
  6  * Name createLinkedList                   *
  7  * Imports: none                           *
  8  * Exports: list (LinkedList)              *
  9  * Assertion: Creates a new linked list    *
 10  ******************************************/
 11 
 12 LinkedList* createLinkedList()
 13 {
 14     LinkedList* list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
 15     list->head = NULL;
 16     list->tail = NULL;
 17     list->size = 0;
 18 
 19     return list;
 20 }
 21 
 22 /****************************************************************
 23  * Name: insertStart                                            *
 24  * Imports: list (LinkedList*), entry (void*)                   *
 25  * Exports: none                                                *
 26  * Assertion: To insert a node at the beginning of the list     *
 27  ***************************************************************/
 28 
 29 void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
 30 {
 31     LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
 32 
 33     newNode->data = entry;
 34     newNode->next = list->head;
 35     newNode->previous = NULL;
 36 
 37     if (list -> head == NULL)
 38     {
 39         list->head = newNode;
 40         list->tail = newNode;
 41         list->size++;
 42     }
 43     else
 44     {
 45         list->head = newNode;
 46         newNode -> next -> previous = newNode;
 47         list->size++;
 48     }
 49 
 50 }
 51 
 52 /***********************************************************************
 53  * Name: removeStart                                                   *
 54  * Imports: list (LinkedList)                                          *
 55  * Exports: none                                                       *
 56  * Assertion: Deletes the first item, returns null if list is empty    *
 57  **********************************************************************/
 58 
 59 void* removeStart(LinkedList* list)
 60 {
 61     LinkedListNode* curr = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
 62 
 63     void* ptr;
 64 
 65     curr = list->head;
 66 
 67     if (curr->next == NULL)
 68     {
 69         free(curr);
 70         list->head = NULL;
 71     }
 72     if (curr->next != NULL)
 73     {
 74         ptr = curr -> data;
 75 
 76         list -> head = curr -> next;
 77 
 78         free(curr);
 79         curr = NULL;
 80 
 81         list -> head -> previous = NULL;
 82         list->size--;
 83     }
 84 
 85 
 86     return ptr;
 87 }
 88 
 89 /************************************************************
 90  * Name: insertLast                                         *
 91  * Imports: list (LinkedList*), entry (void*)               *
 92  * Exports: none                                            *
 93  * Assertion: Imports an element to the back of the list    *
 94  ***********************************************************/
 95 
 96 void insertLast(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
 97 {
 98     LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
 99     LinkedListNode* curr;
100 
101     if (list -> head == NULL)
102     {
103         insertStart(list, entry);
104     }
105     else
106     {
107         newNode->data = entry;
108         newNode->next = NULL;
109 
110         curr = list->head;
111 
112         while (curr->next != NULL)
113         {
114             curr = curr->next;
115         }
116 
117         if (curr->next == NULL)
118         {
119             curr->next = newNode;
120             newNode->previous = curr;
121         }
122 
123         list->tail = newNode;
124         list->size++;
125     }
126 
127 }
128 
129 /*************************************************************************************
130  * Name: removeLast                                                                  *
131  * Imports: list (LinkedList*)                                                       *
132  * Exports: ptr (void*)                                                              *
133  * Assertion: Removes an element from the end, if empty will return null pointer     *
134  ************************************************************************************/
135 
136 void* removeLast(LinkedList* list)
137 {
138     LinkedListNode* curr = list -> head;
139     LinkedListNode* secondLast;
140 
141     void* ptr;
142 
143     if (isEmpty(list) == 0)
144     {
145         printf("List is empty");
146     }
147     else
148     {
149         while (curr->next != NULL)
150         {
151             secondLast = curr;
152             curr = curr->next;
153         }
154 
155         if (curr == list->head)
156         {
157             list -> head = NULL;
158         }
159 
160     }
161 
162     ptr = curr->data;
163     list->size--;
164     secondLast -> next = NULL;
165     list -> tail = secondLast;
166 
167     free(curr);
168     curr = NULL;
169 
170     return ptr;
171 }
201 /******************************************************
202  * Name: freeLinkedList                               *
203  * Imports: list (LinkedList*), funcPtr (listFunc)    *
204  * Exports: none                                      *
205  * Assertion: To free all elements within the list    *
206  *****************************************************/
207 
208 void freeLinkedList(LinkedList* list)
209 {
210     LinkedListNode* curr;
211     LinkedListNode* next;
212 
213     curr = list->head;
214 
215     while (curr != NULL)
216     {
217         next = curr->next;
218         free(curr);
219         curr = next;
220     }
221 
222     free(list);
223 }
```

According to valgrind I keep losing memory and I really don't know what is causing this issue.

Comment: One problem is that there is no main function that shows if and how the functions are called. Probably, valgrind reports the actual problem. Is there a reason to provide huge amount of source code but excluding the report?

Comment: First of all please don't include line-numbers in code you show. It makes it much harder for us to try it out ourselves, or even just copy-paste a single line for explanations. Also please don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve]. And of course remember the *complete* and *reproducible* parts as well.

Comment: Also, are you sure the leak is in your list, and not in the data you store in the list? It would also help a lot if you added the Valgrind output (copy-pasted as text). When it reports a leak, please add a *comment* on the corresponding line in the code you show. And remember to build with debug-information enabled (add the `-g` flag when building), and then Valgrind will show you *exactly* where the leaks and allocations are.

Comment: The formatting of your code is amazing!

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Instead create an answer or accept an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without digging into your program (as the running scenario is missing (i.e. main function is missing)),

If you look at removeStart function:

```
void* removeStart(LinkedList* list)
{
     LinkedListNode* curr = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));  
     void* ptr;
     curr = list->head;
     ...
```

You can see you use `curr` pointer you allocate memory (by calling malloc),

`LinkedListNode* curr = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));`
then you set it to `list->head` (`curr=list->head`), which means you lose the reference to the memory you've just now allocated.

I don't know if there are more memory leaks at your program, however this one is obvious.

I suggest you start by changing this to
`LinkedListNode* curr = list->head`
and run again valgrind to see if you still have leaks.

As mentioned at the comment above, you can get a full report from valgrind, **including the line number at your code which caused the memory leak**.
To get such full report, you need to compile your source code with debug information (add `-g` flag to gcc), then run valgrind with the option  `--leak-check=full`.
valgrind report will now contain the line at code which caused the memory leak.

Comment: Thank you! That did help a lot. Sorry I didn't add the main part, it's just a set of unit tests, testing every function of my linked list code. After having made the suggested change the only issue I have left is 24 bytes in one block that is definitely lost, which is apparently in the insertLast function.

Comment: I edited the answer, to contain explanation how you get information from valgrind what is the exact line of code which allocate memory which is not freed (leak).

Comment: Actually it's all good, I figure it out. in the insertLast function I declared a new variable using malloc but had an if statement saying if the list is empty, use the insertFirst function. As a result I had an unused malloc declared pointer sitting doing nothing. Thanks for your input though, definitely got rid of 90% of my issues.